# Pegar variável em outra página

Tags: php, mysql

Apos buscar os dados no mysql com php e exibi-los na pagina, eu gostaria de saber como faço para pegar esses mesmos resultados dessa pagina onde é exibido e exibi-los em outra pagina.

```
<?php  

//Cria a variavel telefone enviada do formulario na pagina painel.php
$telefone = $_POST['telefone'];

//Verifica se o valor de telefone não é vazio.
if (empty($telefone)) { 
 header("location: painel.php");
 exit;
}
//Conecta com o banco e seleciona os arquivos para efetuar a contagem.
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "pizzaria");
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT nome, numero, endereco from clientes where telefone = $telefone");
$count = mysqli_num_rows($query);

//Se a contagem for 0
if ($count == 0) { ?>
<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    Ops! não encontramos nenhum cliente com este telefone,
    <a href="painel.php" class="alert-link">tente novamente!</a>
</div>
<?php
die;
//Se a contagem for 1
} else {
if ($count == 1) { ?>
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        Encontramos 1 cliente com este telefone!
    </div>
    <?php
}
}
//Mostra todos os resultados encontrados.
while ($resultado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
echo "Cliente: ". $resultado['nome']. "<br/>";
echo "Endereço: ".$resultado['endereco']. "<br/>";
echo "N°: ".$resultado['numero']. "<br/>";
}

?>
```

Eu gostaria de pegar os resultados do array $resultado['nome'], $resultado['endereco'] e $resultado['numero'] e joga-las na pagina "novo-pedido.php" e depois usa-las para inserir em outra tabela no banco.

Comment: usando $_SESSION ou enviando por get ou post..

Comment: Tem em atenção a SQL Injection.

Comment: vou ter que criar um "mini-formulario" pra poder enviar? não existe outra maneira?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.session.php

Comment: só uma observação: `die()` e `exit()` são as mesmas coisas, então porque não padronizar usando apenas um deles, além disso, costume usar `return;` em vez de `die()` ou `exit()`, pois esses métodos foram feitos para matar processos e não para implementação de saída.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar as `session`'s do PHP. É bem fácil de utilizar e só precisa ser iniciada no início do script e então acessar através da variável global `$_SESSION`.

Ná página que executa a consulta:

```
// no início do arquivo
session_start();

// após executar a query
$_SESSION["clientes"] = array();
while ($resultado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $_SESSION["clientes"][] = $resultado;
}
```

Na outra página:

```
// no inicio do arquivo
session_start();

while ($_SESSION["clientes"] as $cliente) {
    var_dump($cliente);
}
```

**Importante:** a função `session_start` deve ser executada somente uma vez e antes de ser executado qualquer comando que exiba informações para o usuário, como `echo`, `print`, ou seja, é recomendado colocar bem no início do arquivo.

**Obs:** não recomendo passar os resultados de uma pesquisa completa via `$_SESSION`. Uma alternativa seria salvar os filtros ou até mesmo a query na session e depois executar novamente na outra página.